# Can't get POST data in django rest framework

Tags: angularjs, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

Here is my view,

```
 @api_view(['GET','POST'])
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        posts = Posts.objects.all()
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        usr = request.data.get('username')
        print(request.data)
        pwd = request.data.get('password')
        try:
            user = Users.objects.get(username=usr)
            if user.password == pwd:
                return Response(UserSerializer(user).data)
            else:
                return Response({})
        except Users.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({})
```

This is my call in angularjs controller

```
$http.post("api/v1/login/",{"username":$scope.username,"password":$scope.password})
           .then(
               function(response){
                 console.log('r',response.data)
               },
               function(response){
                 console.log('e',response)
               }
            );
```

I am getting an empty object in my view.I also added

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```

in angular config as suggested in some blog.the `request.data` is still empty.Where am I doing wrong please guide me properly.Thanks in advance.

**I have updated this post because there is some irrelevant code.The problem should lie in these two blocks of code.Please help**.The get ajax request is working.Only in post ,I can get any data.

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, parser_classes
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser 

@api_view(['GET','POST'])
@parser_classes((FormParser, MultiPartParser))
def login(request):
    ...
```

Comment: I have added as You suggested but still getting an empty object in `print(response.data)` .getting <QueryDict: {'{}': ['']}> in powershell

Comment: Try with MultiPartParser also?

Comment: That MultiPartParser giving me an error on client side saying "Unsupported media type"

Comment: FormParser should have worked. It does for me. Try with 'application/json' and JSONParser?

Comment: where should I put "application/json".was that in angular ajax call contenttype

Comment: `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';`

Comment: No it didn't work either.And I am not using any kind of form in angular template.Just an ajax call when a button is pressed.Does I not using form might be the reason or it is irrelavent

Comment: It shouldn't matter, says here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/ that FormParser will put x-www-form-urlencoded data into request.data.

Comment: Maybe try out your components one-by-one to see where the problem is? Like POST against Django with Postman to see if that side works, look into sent data with Chrome dev tools to see if Angular side works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will check bit by bit as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Install ngCookies then add this line of code:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$log', '$http', '$cookies',
function ($rootScope, $log, $http, $cookies) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
}]);
```

clean your browser and try again.

Comment: Thanks,I already solved the issue.The issue was on my side.I haven't checked the actual data going or not.Sorry for the troble and thanks again.